# Unreal Engine 5.2: Can't create or open C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unreal-engine5

I recently updated to Unreal Engine 5.2 and I can't create a new C++ project. It gives me this error:

*Running E:/!Unreal/UE_5.2/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Build.bat  -projectfiles -project="D:/!Unreal/MyProject/MyProject.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
ERROR: The batch file does not appear to be located in the Engine/Build/BatchFiles directory. This script must be run from within that directory.*

It works just fine when I try to create a blueprint project. If I try to open an already existing UE5.2 project (which wasn't created on my computer and instead pulled from github), I get the message to rebuild the missing modules, but then get an error that the project could not be compiled and to build it from source. When I try to generate VS project files I get the previous error:

*Running E:/!Unreal/UE_5.2/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Build.bat -projectfiles -project=“E:/!UnrealProjects/Space-Innovators/SpaceInnovators.uproject” -game -rocket -progress -log=“E:!UnrealProjects\Space-Innovators/Saved/Logs/UnrealVersionSelector-2023.08.04-21.19.45.log”
ERROR: The batch file does not appear to be located in the Engine/Build/BatchFiles directory. This script must be run from within that directory.*

Things I have tried that didn't work:

reinstalling Unreal Engine, reinstalling VS, pulling the project again, moving the project directory to the disk where Unreal Engine is installed (they were on different disks, still nothing), restarting my computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it myself, the problem was comming from the Unreal Engine directory because it begins with "!". I've installed all my other versions in this directory, never had such problem before.

Comment: @Boisbois2 what is "this directory"?